# what would be the right way to run and express generated app with pm2 on linux

Tags: pm2, express-generator

how would be the right way to run an express-generator created with pm2 ? 
which would be the right adjustments i should make to run with pm2?

As it says in his [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) I should run the app like : 
DEBUG=myapp:* npm start

Thats ok when i run with npm but what should I change to run it with pm2?
in the package.js file lays..

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
  },
```

I have changed this to like, but is not added in pm2 monit:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have done like this:

In terminal run the app like

```
 pm2  start  ./bin/www
```

where resides de app.
that way it will run a your app as a "www" and you can monitor with pm2 monit.